# Submitting FormB upon submission of FormA using VBScript.ASP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, vbscript

My client has a long subscription form (FormB). They've asked me to send out an email to a rental list of contacts, asking them to subscribe.

They want to use FormB, which is on their website, but are concerned that it might be too long and would put people off subscribing. I do not have dev access to FormB.

I would like to create an identical form (FormA), one which can pre-populate based on the contact details that I have in my database when a contact clicks through from my email. The client feels this would make the subscription process easier.

Is there a way using VBScript.ASP and/or JavaScript to pass the submitted values from FormA to FormB, and submit FormB automatically when they click submit on FormA?

Thanks in advance for the help. I'm happy to provide more details if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, and only requiring HTML. I just needed to amend the action of my FormA tag to the URL of FormB, like so:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="http://FormBURL.com">
    <-- form fields -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

although i dont know vbscript, what you can do is take all values and send those values to the formb controller by query params if it accepts GET or send it using same object if it only accepts POST. I hope this might have cleared what you need to do